# How do I stop showing Adsense to someone if they reject cookies?

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense, gdpr

I have a Wordpress site and have just installed a cookie banner to get consent. I have a few questions about this though, what do I do if somebody clicks "reject"? How do I stop showing them the Adsense on my website?

Does this need to be done through coding? I am aware Adsense have created a new code which needs to be added before all adverts which essentially says "check if this person is okay to receive adverts", so is that all I need to do?

I've searched a lot for this particular question but can't find an answer and I want to ensure I am GDPR compliant.

Comment: Do you _need_ to "stop showing Adsense if they reject cookies"?

Comment: Yes as the cookie policy and next year's EU law means I'm technically in the wrong for not doing so already.

Answer (score 1):

*You can do this by loading your scripts using a simple if cookie check, e.g*

- JavaScript Native: [navigator.cookieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4603313/1892635)
- JavaScript Library: [Modernizer 'Cookies'](https://modernizr.com/docs)
- PHP: [$_COOKIE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832817/1892635)

Comment: Thanks, does this mean the banner can just say 'we use cookies' then run a script which checks? There's no interaction between the banner and the script? Is the above script correct if I were to c&p or do I need to do a but more googling?

Comment: It means that PHP or JavaScript will check the ability to 'write a cookie' then if 'TRUE' then it loads the Adsense JavaScript. PHP is my preferred method and not you can't copy and paste, you need to write the code, use Stack Overflow as programming related questions are off-topic on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: This assumes users have actively blocked cookies in their browser, which is not usually what happens when a user responds to a "cookie banner" on a website (as stated in the question). If the user has actually blocked cookies in the browser then there is no reason to block Adsense, since no third party cookies will be set anyway (the Adsense served will just not be "personalized"). GDPR isn't about blocking adverts/AdSense, it is about blocking non-essential cookies (that _personalized_ adverts are dependent on). Non-personalized adverts can still be served with cookies disabled.

Comment: "PHP is my preferred method" - although you can't determine whether cookies are _writeable_  on the _initial request_ using a PHP-only solution. However, whether cookies are physically writeable or not is not what the question is asking.

Comment: @DocRoot that's true but I meant to say I prefer using PHP with JS, but the even better method which I've used lately is GTM.